# Error while successful "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full"

Tags: ubuntu, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I got stuck while installation. See below for the detail. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Phenom**:

- While running "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full", after downloading a few hundred MB of data, it suddenly quitted and showed "E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-desktop-full". I did NOT touch the computer during the downloading period.
- Output of apt-get update: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yxY6w5v6jedHXnc3omkEwCkxlT4abejfEtz3tF-D9ek/edit?hl=en_US

  <- For the ROS part, the result is the same on another computer that successfully installed diamondback.
- Output of installable ROS packages on the computer. You'll see diamondback packages are missing: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=10DGLH84UZKyXp1itsPAZl8S0m0ZdsVUZ1R8ZpSyiIfw

**Tried workaround**:

- The things discussed in the pages below are already tried (incl. allowing universe & multi-universe etc.)

http://answers.ros.org/question/702/unable-to-find-install-package

http://answers.ros.org/question/120/troubles-installing-ros-c-turtle-base

- sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*ros*
- Reboot OS.
- "sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list" and start over.

**Other**: Another computer which is on the same network has successfully installed diamondback. And after apt-get update on the same machine, apt-get still shows ros-diamondback as installable packages.

**Env**: Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick, Kernel Linux 2.6.35-30-generic-pae

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10813/error-while-successful-%22sudo-apt-get-install-ros-diamondback-desktop-full%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-04**:
@tfoote @Patrick Bouffard sorry again. I replaced with the new URL (turned out my setting on G-docs was correct though).

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-04**:
Me either. Use pastebin, it's better.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-04**:
I still can't follow the 2nd link.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-04**:
Oops, sorry. I switch to the original long URL, and also switched to public instead of "anyone with link" on G-docs.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-03**:
Your bit.ly link doesn't work--it apparently links to a Google Doc that isn't world readable. Maybe try pastebin instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a workaround by myself. From [mirror sites](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors), I chose Case Western and did the same for the rest of steps.
Then I was able to see ros-diamondback* and now download is in process.

Before then, I also tried Maryland but it returned the same result with the issue above.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-04**:
@tfoote thanks, I'm glad you've fixed the problem and also the mirror site did its job.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-04**:
Yeah, we had a bug in our distro script which invalidated the entire repository on maverick.  It should be restored now.